# getting leak trying to release NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I'm getting memory leak releasing NSMutableArray in a UIViewController that spins up, then in ViewDidLoad it allocs and inits the array, adds objects to it; and then when view closes:  its dealloc() releases each array object, then releases the array.

And a leak usually results.

My basic structure: ...

```
...m  file:

NSMutableArray* foo;

@implementation ....

viewDidLoad
{
[[foo  alloc]  init];
...
}

dealloc
{
  for i = each foo object:
    [foo  objectAtIndex: i]  release];

    [foo  release];
}
```

...

Comment: do you really need to run a for loop to release each of the object? I believe a `release` message is sent to each of the items in an array when the array itself is released.

Comment: Please add actual code. As such you don't need to release objects that you've added to the array. Array retains them and will release them when deallocated.

Comment: @Deepak y did u downvote to me

Answer (score 1):

The leak in this case can result when the items in your array are being `retain`ed elsewhere. Sending a `release` message to that item will just decrease its retain count and will not actually dealloc it.

Answer (score 1):

When releasing a NSMutableArray, it handles releasing all it's children.  Same goes for NSArray, NSMutableDictionary, NSDictionary, etc etc.

Try setting up foo as an instance variable in your header and then synthesize it:

```
...h file
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray* foo;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *foo;

...m file
@implementation ....
@synthesize foo;

viewDidLoad
{
    self.foo = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]  init];
    ...
}

dealloc
{
    [foo  release];
}
```

Comment: Somehow I think he is doing almost exactly the same thing here which is the reason he must be getting the leak. `self.foo = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]  init];` has 2 retains and you are releasing only once in the end.